# Upgrading Chrome to v65 causes table contents to move right and out from the column headings

Tags: html, google-chrome, row

Tables that used to appear like this in Chrome:

```
----------------------------------
| Header A | Header B | Header C |
----------------------------------
| Item 1   |          |          |
----------------------------------
| Item 2   | Stuff 1  |  Stuff 2 |
----------------------------------
```

...after upgrading Chrome to v65 now appear like this:

```
---------------------------------------------
| Header A | Header B | Header C |          |
---------------------------------------------
| Item 1   | Item 2   | Stuff 1  |  Stuff 2 |
---------------------------------------------
```

Firefox v59 also renders the table this last way, so this probably only suddenly affects those who have Chrome-only systems.

The source might look something like this:

```
<table>
 <tr> <th>Header A</th><th>Header B</th><th>Header C</th> </tr>
 <tr> <td rowspan="0">Item 1</td> </tr>
 <tr> <td rowspan="1">Item 2</td><td>Stuff 1</td><td>Stuff 2</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome used to render a row with an attribute `rowspan="0"` as either 0 height or 1 height. Chrome v65 now renders it 'properly' as given in the [html spec here](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#adef-rowspan). This means that the entry now fills the first column, pushing all following entries into the next column and so out to the right.

This may be caused by, for example, html renderers that calculate how many rows a cell might take according to a list of sub-items, when that list is empty. (For example improve-foundation's struts-layout does this; it does not appear to have been maintained since 2011 and attempts to register on the site fail me for now)